# Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a proper smooth map with continuous extension $F : \mathbb C P^1 \to \mathbb C P^1$. Must $F$ be smooth?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-functions, riemann-sphere

We know that, if $p : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a nontrivial polynomial, then the function $P: \mathbb C P^1 \to \mathbb C P^1$ defined as $P([z:1]) = [p(z):1]$ and $P([1:0]) = [1:0]$ is a smooth map; this can be checked in a straightforward manner.

I am wondering if this can be generalized to a general proper smooth map $f: \mathbb C \to C$, i.e. whether

(1) The function $F: \mathbb C P^1 \to \mathbb C P^1$ defined as $F([z:1]) = [f(z):1]$ and $F([1:0]) = [1:0]$ is continuous, and

(2) Whether the function $F$ thus defined is smooth.

I am told that the answer for (1) is true while the answer for (2) is no. However, I am having a hard time proving this. It would be great if you could provide a counterexample to (2).

EDIT: I made an important edit, that the map $f$ is smooth proper map.

Comment: The statement (1) is definitely not correct, even for holomorphic functions. What happens if $f(z)=e^z$? Can you not take your favorite function that is not differentiable (or $C^1$) at the origin and transplant that behavior to infinity?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin thank you for your input. I am wondering if there is a way to modify the definition of $F$ so that we will have a continuous map?

Comment: No. Did you think about what it means for $e^z$ to have an essential singularity at $\infty$? You need $F$ to have a limit at infinity.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you. I made an important edit, namely that $f$ should be a proper map.

Comment: Ah, properness will get you the continuity. You need to correct your definition, however.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you, could you provide a bit of guidance? I am really lost on this. Where is the fact that $f^{-1}(K)$ being compact if $K$ is compact used?

Comment: Think of a sequence of points converging to $\infty$.